# Did any one worked on Aruba Beacon integration in Swift without Meridian Account?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, ibeacon, aruba

I am trying to integrate the Aruba Beacon integration in my project to do POC.I took 5piece of Aruba Beacon set pack. i got the UUID of 5piece beacons by using some android application, but having same UUID for all 5 Aruba Beacon devices with major/minor values 0/0.  I don't have Meridian Account(Aruba Beacon account) as it cost more. Can any one provide information how to get/set the major/minor values of Aruba beacon to make the each individual beacon as unique to identify.

Any help will be appreciated..

Comment: Did you fix ...??

Comment: Also looking for the answer